# How to connect several jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

See the example here - http://jsfiddle.net/d1st/KyWqR/5/

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabs2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>



$(function () {
    $("#tabs, #tabs2").tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        hide: 'blind', 
        show: 'blind',
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false
    });
});
```

This is two separated tab-containers (two different rows).
This is what I need, but I want to make so:

if I open tab in second row, then tab in first row should close.
As if i open/close tabs in same row (in same container).

How can i do it?

Thaks for your answers.

Comment: You'll have to create a JS method that captures the clicks and then closes all other open tabs.

Comment: Yeap, I understand this. 
But the answer from SarathSprakash sometimes work not correct.
I think code should be very little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my own decision!

```
    var a;
$("#tab-main-block > div").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    hide: 'blind',
    show: 'blind',
    active: false,
    autoHeight: false
});
$("#tab-main-block > div ul li").click(function () {
    $("#tab-main-block > div ul li").not(this).attr('aria-selected','false');
    $("#tab-main-block > div ul li").not(this).attr('class','ui-state-default ui-corner-top');
    a = $(this).parents().eq(1);
    $("#tab-main-block > div").not(a).children().not("ul").slideUp(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KyWqR/7/)**

Try this

```
$(function () {
    var a;
    var b;
    $("#tabs, #tabs2").tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        hide: 'blind',
        show: 'blind',
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false
    });
    $("#tabs ul li").click(function () {
       a=$(this);
        b.attr('aria-selected','false');
        b.attr('class','ui-state-default ui-corner-top');
       $("#tabs2").children().not("ul").slideUp();
    });
     $("#tabs2 ul li").click(function () {
         b=$(this);
         a.attr('aria-selected','false');
         a.attr('class','ui-state-default ui-corner-top');
     $("#tabs").children().not("ul").slideUp();
    });
    });
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: Thank you! But sometimes code is buggy.
Then one tab open and you click on another - sometimes only the first tab closes.